# PostgreSQL - left join generate_series() and table

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I use generate series to create a series of numbers from 0 to 200.

I have a table that contains dirtareas in mm² in a column called polutionmm2. What I need is to left join this table to the generated series, but the dirt area must be in cm² so /100. I was not able to make this work, as I can't figure out how I can connect a table to a series that has no name.

This Is what I have so far:

```
select  generate_series(0,200,1) as x,  cast(p.polutionmm2/100 as char(8)) as metric   
from x
    left join polutiondistributionstatistic as p on metric = x
```

error: relation X does not exist

Here is some sample data: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3d7d851887adb938819d6cf3e5849719

what I would need, is the first column (x) counting all the way from 0 to 200, and where there is a matching value, to show it in the second column.

Like this:

```
x, metric
0, 0
1, 1
2, 2
3, null
4, 4
5, null
... , ...
... , ...
200, null
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `generate_series()` in the `FROM`.  So, I think you want something like this:

```
select gs.x, cast(p.polutionmm2/100 as char(8)) as metric
from generate_series(0,200,1) gs(x) left join
     p
     on gs.x = (p.polutionmm2/100);
```

I imagine there is also more to your query, because this doesn't do much that is useful.

Comment: Yep my query is longer, and i need to use this to generate rows even for values that do not exist intermediately.. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3d7d851887adb938819d6cf3e5849719 like for example the "300" in this sample. It does not seem to work tough, i get that gs.x must appear in a group by clause or aggregate function...

Comment: For me, this solution works well. What is the problem? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=74bfc30fa62f8cf1b338edcec1a016da

Comment: @S-Man thank you, it is working now was a error on my side.. tough it is not giving me the result I am expecting. Since i am doing a left join i expect the left table to preserve all rows.. so i expect for example row number 3 to be there... thank you

Comment: @sharkyenergy . . . this keeps all values generated by the `generate_series()`.  With no `where`, you should get all of them, including `3`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yep, i noticed that the where clause is causing me trouble...trying to fix it..

Comment: @sharkyenergy . . . You should probably move it to the `on` clause.  But that is outside the scope of the question asked here.

Comment: that is what I did but its not working.. going to create a new question. thanks for your help